# Item not being deleted from database asp.net

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, telerik

I am using entity framework to populate a grid but im trying to delete the item but no error is hapening just no action.

My Grid is as follows iont no what the issue is to be honest because i am using type player so it should be deleting.

I Havent got any futher with this can someone please giveme a hand.

```
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="grdSoccerPlayers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"    GroupPanelPosition="Top" AutoGenerateDeleteColumn="True" AutoGenerateEditColumn="True" OnItemCommand="grdSoccerPlayers_ItemCommand" CellSpacing="-1" GridLines="Both" AllowAutomaticDeletes="True">

        <MasterTableView    CommandItemDisplay="Top">
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="id" DataType="System.Guid" FilterControlAltText="Filter id column" HeaderText="id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" UniqueName="id">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" FilterControlAltText="Filter Name column" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Name" UniqueName="Name">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="player_id" FilterControlAltText="Filter player_id column" HeaderText="player_id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="player_id" UniqueName="player_id">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="gender" FilterControlAltText="Filter gender column" HeaderText="gender" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="gender" UniqueName="gender">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="town" FilterControlAltText="Filter town column" HeaderText="town" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="town" UniqueName="town">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="telephone" FilterControlAltText="Filter telephone column" HeaderText="telephone" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="telephone" UniqueName="telephone">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="email" FilterControlAltText="Filter email column" HeaderText="email" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="email" UniqueName="email">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="active" DataType="System.Boolean" FilterControlAltText="Filter active column" HeaderText="active" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="active" UniqueName="active">
                </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="createdDate" DataType="System.DateTime" FilterControlAltText="Filter createdDate column" HeaderText="createdDate" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="createdDate" UniqueName="createdDate">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="author" FilterControlAltText="Filter author column" HeaderText="author" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="author" UniqueName="author">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="teamId" DataType="System.Guid" FilterControlAltText="Filter teamId column" HeaderText="teamId" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="teamId" UniqueName="teamId">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="address" FilterControlAltText="Filter address column" HeaderText="address" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="address" UniqueName="address">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                <telerik:GridButtonColumn CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" UniqueName="Delete"
     ButtonType="ImageButton" ImageUrl="~/Icons/delete.png" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" HeaderText="Actions"
     ConfirmTitle="Delete" ConfirmDialogType="Classic"   
     ConfirmText="Are you sure want to delete the selected player?" />
            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid> 

        if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
            {
                GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
                Guid strId = new Guid(item.GetDataKeyValue("id").ToString());

                player _player = _dal.GetPlayerBYID(strId);
                _dal.SoccerEntities.AddToplayers(_player);
                _dal.SoccerEntities.DeleteObject(_player);

                _dal.SoccerEntities.SaveChanges();
                grdSoccerPlayers.DataBind();
                grdSoccerPlayers.Rebind();
            }
```

My Data source is a linq query as follows

```
     public player GetPlayerBYID(Guid _playerId)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_playerId == Guid.Empty)
                {
                    player _player = new player();
                    _player.player_id = "16-56-232";
                    return _player;
                }
                else
                {
                    var q = SoccerEntities.players.Where(p => p.id == _playerId);

                    if (q == null)
                        throw new EntityContextException(string.Format("A player could not be found {0}!", _playerId));
                    else
                        return q.ToList()[0];
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new EntityContextException("GetPlayerBYID failed.", ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why are you exactly using GUID? Why not using the primary key or a simple identity type like a Unique value? The GUID is the problem, use the ID as it is instead.

Comment: Is the item you're trying to delete a foreign key to another table? SQL will stop you if that item is a foreign key in another table. So it will execute with no errors, but nothing will happen.

Comment: A Team can have many players just but the player is not a foreign key its self

Comment: @Timmy SEE ABOVE  a player can be in a team ie a team can have many players but it should be ok to deelte that

Comment: @Transcendent Guid is not the probelm it is a unqiue value !

Comment: @kymberly: but are you sure that unique value matches something in your DB?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are missing an OnDeleteCommand. Check out the documentation for this control. http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-editing/delete-records/overview

Comment: no im not missing it please look at the code and understand that im calling delete object manually on item command